# Effective ways in Counting Number of Occurrences for a time series data using R in a specific time period

Tags: r, time-series

I am dealing with a time series data from a hospital using R which looks like

```
         Time of Arrival    Time of Treatment
         8/1/14 12:14 AM    8/1/14 12:26 AM
         8/1/14 12:22 AM    8/1/14 12:35 AM
         8/1/14 12:47 AM    8/1/14 12:56 AM
         8/1/14 1:07 AM     8/1/14 1:16 AM
         8/1/14 1:19 AM     8/1/14 1:32 AM
         8/1/14 1:53 AM     8/1/14 2:02 AM
          8/1/14 1:56 AM    8/1/14 2:18 AM
          8/1/14 1:58 AM    8/1/14 2:15 AM
```

This is essentially about the arrival of patients  in ED department and when they are treated. I have data for complete one year and working on building a regression based model to predict the time taken for patients to be treated. For this, I have divided my whole dataset in a period of 20 mins (12.00 A.M to 12.20 A.M and so on) and based on this count how many patients  arrived  in 20 mins time frame.  Currently, I am using a two step process
1. Count the number of patients between the two specific period
2. Allocating the calculated number back to the specific time period.

For performing 2nd task, I am using following code

```
     for (i in 1:nrow(date))
      {for (j in 1:nrow(period)){
        if (date[i,1]>=period[j,]){ 
        j=j+1
        z[i,]=t[j,]}
        }
          i=i+1
             }
```

Unfortunately, 2nd step is taking too much time to be done, I was wondering is there any efficient way by which I can perform my 2nd task ? I am new to R and using two levels of for loops is making computing time too large.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: it is somewhat unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to count how many patients arrived during a certain time period?

Comment: Yes that is first part and it is working fine, when allocating back this number to the specific entry is taking time

Comment: Ok, so the rows of z lines up with date (which is Time of Arrival in the input data) and z is desired output, which is the count for that 20 min period that date is in? Also the rows of t lines up with period and t is the counted number of patients in the 20 min period? What is the Time of Treatment column used for?

Answer (score 1):

Counting how many patients are present in a given time-period i define a patient as present if:

- He arrives before the period ends
- He is treated after the period begins

Altering your dataset instead of 12 AM to 0 AM:

```
require(data.table)

text = "arr;tre
8/1/14 0:14 AM;8/1/14 0:26 AM
8/1/14 0:22 AM;8/1/14 0:35 AM
8/1/14 0:47 AM;8/1/14 0:56 AM
8/1/14 1:07 AM; 8/1/14 1:16 AM
8/1/14 1:19 AM; 8/1/14 1:32 AM
8/1/14 1:53 AM; 8/1/14 2:02 AM
8/1/14 1:56 AM;8/1/14 2:18 AM
8/1/14 1:58 AM;8/1/14 2:15 AM"
```

Reading and parsing data:

```
dat <- fread(text, sep = ";")
dat[,c("arr", "tre") := .(as.POSIXct(arr, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p"), as.POSIXct(tre, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p"))]
dat[,`:=`(arr_d = as.IDate(arr),
          arr_t = as.ITime(arr),
          tre_d = as.IDate(tre),
          tre_t = as.ITime(tre))]
dat[,c("arr", "tre") := NULL]
```

you can use `data.table`'s new semi-joins. This is a new feature in `data.table` 1.9.7 so you need the development version. Find the installation-guidelines [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Create a `data.table` with the start and end-times of your periods:

```
mp <- data.table(period_start = seq(as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 0:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 03:00"), by = "20 min"))
mp <- mp[, period_end := shift(period_start, 1, type = "lead")][-.N]
mp[,`:=`(ps_d = as.IDate(period_start),
         ps_t = as.ITime(period_start),
         pe_d = as.IDate(period_end),
         pe_t = as.ITime(period_end))]
mp[,c("period_start", "period_end") := NULL]
```

Run the join:

```
res <- dat[mp,.(ps_d, ps_t, pe_d, pe_t, x.arr_d, x.arr_t, x.tre_d, x.tre_t), 
           on=.(arr_d <= pe_d, arr_t <= pe_t,
                tre_d >= ps_d, tre_t >= ps_t), nomatch=NA, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Have a look at res. You can double check the categorization of the patients.

Count the number of patients by period_start

```
res[,sum(!is.na(x.arr_d)), by=.(ps_d, ps_t)]
```

This results in:

```
         ps_d     ps_t V1
1: 2014-07-31 00:00:00  1
2: 2014-07-31 00:20:00  2
3: 2014-07-31 00:40:00  1
4: 2014-07-31 01:00:00  2
5: 2014-07-31 01:20:00  1
6: 2014-07-31 01:40:00  3
7: 2014-08-01 02:00:00  3
8: 2014-08-01 02:20:00  0
9: 2014-08-01 02:40:00  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This solves one part of my problem. For the second step, I want to allocate the number of person against time of arrival i.e. for 1st entry  8/1/14 12:14 AM we have "1" as it falls in 1st interval for   8/1/14 12:22 AM  "1" as it falls under 3rd interval and so on, I am confused on how to do this part

Comment: What do you mean by _allocate_? If you mean plot try `lines(res2[,sum(!is.na(arr_proxy)),period_start])`

Comment: I want to create  one more column with this entry as it serve as one of the variable for my further  analysis.

Comment: And what should be in this new column? Maybe you can edit your answer and add the expected output

Comment: My Apologies If I am confusing,To be clear I will post more details: so The entire data set has

Comment: My Apologies If I am confusing,To be clear I will post more details. So the entire dataset has Timestamp right including  Patient's Arrival Time, Triage Time, Treatment Time and Disposition Time. I intend to find the count of how many people are there between Arrival &Triage, Triage & Treatment, Treatment& Disposition for 20 min time frame.  I have a function which does this count, but when I try to map it back i.e how many people were there between   Arrival &Triage, Triage & Treatment, Treatment& Disposition I am not able to do that. Hope I am clear now